# Is a closed compact 2-Manifold that is embedded in euclidean 3-space always orientable?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, surfaces

I am sorry if this is a trivial question but I am a little confused right now so please bear with me.

Since non-orientable compact 2-manifolds without boundary cannot
be embedded in three-dimensional Euclidean space is it true that all compact 2-manifolds without boundary embedded in three-dimensional Euclidean space are orientable?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Isn't that the contrapositive?

Comment: @Gaffney: you are missing $\partial M=\varnothing$ in the contrapositive

Comment: consider the related [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112538/does-every-orientable-surface-embed-in-mathbbr3]

Comment: also [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem#Restrictions_on_manifolds]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the proof in the smooth setting is easier, one also has the same conclusion in the topological setting:

Lemma. Let $M^{n-1}$ be a closed (compact and without boundary) connected topological  manifold such that there exists $f: M\to R^n$, a topological embedding. (No assumption is made about $f(M)$ being a submanifold.) Then $M$ is orientable.

Proof. The proof is by applying twice the Poincare-Alexander duality to the subset $f(M)$ in $R^n$. First, apply it with $Z_2$ coefficients to conclude that $R^n\setminus f(M)$ has at least two components. Then apply duality again to conclude that $H^{n-1}(M; {\mathbb Z})$ is nonzero, i.e., is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}$. Therefore, $M$ has to be oriented. qed

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a smooth compact hypersurface (with no boundary) in $\Bbb R^n$ (more generally, in any simply connected manifold) is always orientable.

Comment: The submanifold was not assumed to be smooth. Moreover, the image of embedding was not assumed to be a submanifold.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Also for anyone looking for a short proof please see here: [Orientability
of
Hypersurface in R^n](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-01/S0002-9939-1969-0245026-9/S0002-9939-1969-0245026-9.pdf)